# Unable to create Allure report issue python/selenium/behave

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, allure, python-behave

I'm following a tutorial, and have a issue trying to create allure-report, receiving the following message:

```
usage: behave [options] [ [DIR|FILE|FILE:LINE] ]+
behave: error: format=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter is unknown
```

What I'm missing and doing wrong? please explain it to me

**Specs:**

- Python 3.11
- Selenium 4

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `pip install allure-behave`
2. I also installed on VSC the Allure Support extension
3. Then I use: `behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o reports/ features`

**Results:**
I have this error:

```
usage: behave [options] [ [DIR|FILE|FILE:LINE] ]+
behave: error: format=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter is unknown
-Tried with the steps from the pypi.org and nothing. and different dummy variations
```

Comment: any resolution in here? im facing same issue